# Pandas groupby with dict

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use a dict to group on elements of a column?

For example:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three','two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
   ...:          'B' : np.random.randn(8)})
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
       A         B
0    one  0.751612
1    one  0.333008
2    two  0.395667
3  three  1.636125
4    two  0.916435
5    two  1.076679
6    one -0.992324
7  three -0.593476

In [5]: d = {'one':'Start', 'two':'Start', 'three':'End'}
In [6]: grouped = df[['A','B']].groupby(d)
```

This (and other variations) returns an empty groupby object.  And my variations on using `.apply` all fail too.

I'd like to match the values of column `A` to the keys of the dictionary and put rows into the groups defined by the values. The output would look something like this:

```
 Start:
           A         B
    0    one  0.751612
    1    one  0.333008
    2    two  0.395667
    4    two  0.916435
    5    two  1.076679
    6    one -0.992324
End:
           A         B
    3  three  1.636125
    7  three -0.593476
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups), the dict has to map from *labels* to group names, so this will work if you put `'A'` into the index:

```
grouped2 = df.set_index('A').groupby(d)
for group_name, data in grouped2:
    print group_name
    print '---------'
    print data

# Output:
End
---------
              B
A              
three -1.234795
three  0.239209

Start
---------
            B
A            
one -1.924156
one  0.506046
two -1.681980
two  0.605248
two -0.861364
one  0.800431
```

Column names and row indices are both *labels*, whereas before you put `'A'` into the index, the elements of `'A'` are *values*.

If you have other info in the index that makes doing a `set_index()` tricky, you can just create a grouping column with `map()`:

```
df['group'] = df['A'].map(d)
grouped3 = df.groupby('group')
```

Comment: thanks - appreciate the tip on making the new column quickly too

Answer (score 5):

You can group with a dictionary, but (as with any group by operation) you need to set the index column first.

```
grouped = df.set_index("A").groupby(d)

list(grouped)
# [('End',               B
# A              
# three -1.550727
# three  1.048730
# 
# [2 rows x 1 columns]), ('Start',             B
# A            
# one -1.552152
# one -2.018647
# two -0.968068
# two  0.449016
# two -0.374453
# one  0.116770
# 
# [6 rows x 1 columns])]
```

Comment: thanks - (and to Marius) - so only df columns can group on themselves?

Comment: (inadvertent 'enter')

Comment: The index needs to be kept - it's a 5minute time intervals (over 13 years).  So if I want a grouping of (one, two) and (three) as above, the appropriate option is to create a new column with that mapping and then group on that new column?

Comment: @ChristopherShort: If you can't really change the index, then you might be better off doing this by creating a grouping column, see my edited answer