# Convert values into fewer categories and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
In [73]: df
Out[73]: 
         sector from_country to_country            val
0   Agriculture          DEU        DEU       0.000000
1   Agriculture          DEU        USA     189.885777
2   Agriculture          USA        DEU    1087.252361
3   Agriculture          USA        USA       0.000000
4          Food          DEU        DEU       0.000000
5          Food          DEU        USA    1369.047822
6          Food          USA        DEU     954.436445
7          Food          USA        USA       0.000000
8          Wood          DEU        DEU       0.000000
9          Wood          DEU        USA     151.803567
10         Wood          USA        DEU     122.148539
11         Wood          USA        USA       0.000000
```

I want to group the `sector` column such that there are a smaller number of values, then aggregate `val` over the levels of `from_country` and `to_country`.

If the aggregations are like this:

```
agg = {'Agriculture': 'a', 'Food': 'a', 'Wood': 'b'}
```

then I'd want the output to look like:

```
  agg    from_country    to_country val
    a             DEU           DEU 0
                  DEU           USA 1558.933599
                  USA           DEU 2041.688806
                  USA           USA 0
    b             DEU           DEU 0
                  DEU           USA 151.803567
                  USA           DEU 122.148539
                  USA           USA 0
```

Despite having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736127/pandas-groupby-with-dict) about `GroupBy` with a dictionary, I can't quite seem to get this to work.

The closest I can get is this:

```
In [81]: df.set_index(['sector', 'from_country', 'to_country']).groupby(agg, level='sector').sum()
Out[81]: 
                  val
sector               
a         3600.622404
b          273.952107
```

Comment: I think that link is applying overwriting your sector values so `df['sector'] = df['sector'].map(agg)` and then set this to your index or groupby it

Comment: Yes, that works. Shame to have to create a new column/overwrite. I always think that solutions that require this feel a bit hacky. But no real reason why I should think that!

Comment: Well it may be something useful as a feature request but this would be how I would do this and it works, in essence you're categorising the sector's to a higher level so you could add this as a new column and then groupby it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built on @EdChum's idea, you can use `df['sector'].map(agg)` together with the other two columns `from_country` and `to_country` as external columns to do the `groupby`. (the default setting `as_index=True` will make sure these three external columns will appear as index and thus be included in the result.)

```
df['val'].groupby([df['sector'].map(agg), df['from_country'], df['to_country']]).sum().reset_index()

  sector from_country to_country        val
0      a          DEU        DEU     0.0000
1      a          DEU        USA  1558.9336
2      a          USA        DEU  2041.6888
3      a          USA        USA     0.0000
4      b          DEU        DEU     0.0000
5      b          DEU        USA   151.8036
6      b          USA        DEU   122.1485
7      b          USA        USA     0.0000
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you could group by transformed columns like this. +1